# How does the Pow() function work in Python in a mathematical equation?

Tags: python-3.x, pow

Creating a mortgage Calculator, including 3 programmer-specified inputs (amount borrowed, interest rate, and 30 year payback period).

**I am trying to turn this mathematical equation**

```
    (p * (1 + r)n * r) / ((1 + r)n - 1)
```

into code using variables, n will represent the squared user input

then I have to print out a summary of the all three inputs and the sum of the above equation.

**First I imported math and tried the following**

```
math.pow(an, 2)
int(pow(an, 2))
int(math.pow(an, 2))
```

Even when I tried without the pow function it wouldn't work

```
(amt * (1+per)an** * per)/((1+per)an** - 1)
```

## Below is my current code:

```
    import math

    #input values
    amt = input("Amount Borrowed:")
    per = input("Annual interest rate:")
    an = input("Payback period:")

    #output values
    mo = (amt * (1+per)pow(an, 2) * per)/((1+per)pow(an, 2) - 1)

    #summary
    print("Amount Borrowed: ",  amt)
    print("Annual Interest Rate:", per)
    print("Total Years of Payments:", an)
    print("Your monthly mortgage payment is: {mo:.2f}")
```

Example of expected results:

```
Amount borrowed (programmer input) = $270000
Annual interest rate (programmer input) = 5.125%
Payback period (programmer input) = 30 Years
Monthly payment (calculated output) = $1470.11
```

Errors:

```
mo = (amt * (1+per)pow(an, 2) * per)/((1+per)pow(an, 2) - 1)
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
mo = (amt * (1+per)an** * per)/((1+per)an** - 1)
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can't write `a(b)` to multiply `a` and `b`. Python syntax doesn't exactly match typical math syntax.

You're trying to do that when you write

```
(1+per)pow(an, 2)
```

You need to explicitly put a `*` in there if you want to multiply:

```
(1+per) * pow(an, 2)
```

Comment: Yes that helped! I was finally about to test the input

Comment: @Melly222 `input` returns a string, not numbers.

Comment: Amount Borrowed:100000
Annual interest rate:3.5
Payback period (years):25

Comment: @Melly222 Again, `input` returns a string, not numbers.